# Round number to nearest thousand, up or down depending on the number

Tags: javascript

I want to round up a number to the nearest thousand, at the moment I'm using this:

```
Math.ceil(value/1000)*1000;
```

But this goes always up, if I type 1001 it will go to 2000, I want to go up or down depeding on the number, for example 1001 goes to 1000 or 1400 goes to 1000 but 1500 goes to 2000

EDIT:

```
if(value<1000){
  value = 1000;
}else{
  value = Math.round(value/1000)*1000;
}
```

Comment: `Math.round` and not `Math.ceil`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
Math.round(value/1000)*1000
```

examples:

```
Math.round(1001/1000)*1000
1000
Math.round(1004/1000)*1000
1000
Math.round(1500/1000)*1000
2000
```

Comment: Yeah but with round if I type 1 it will not go up to 1000 and this has to round too, if I type 1 it has to go to 1000, an If will work yes I know this, just wanted to know if maybe there was another way.

Comment: @GustavoSanchez You want to ignore 0? You can just check for 0 and set it to 1000 then.

Comment: I want that if 1 is the value it rounds to 1000, always to the nearest thousand.

Comment: @GustavoSanchez 0 is a multiple of 1000, and is the nearest.

Comment: @GustavoSanchez you want Math.max(Math.round(value/1000)*1000,1000) if you want nearest thousand plus minimum of 1000

Comment: If you want to round up, replace `.round` with `.ceil`. To always round down, replace `.round` with `.floor`. I had to do this on a project and the ask was to round up to the nearest 1,000.

Answer (score 3):

By using ES3 Number method, it performs a rounding if no decimal place defined.

```
(value / 1000).toFixed() * 1000
```

---

The original answer was:

```
(value / 1000).toFixed(3) * 1000;
```

Yet this is incorrect, due to the value will return the exact original number, instead of affecting the ceil/floor on the value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var rest = number % 1000; 
if(rest > 500) 
{ number = number - rest + 1000; } 
  else 
{ number = number - rest; }
```

maybe a bit straight forward.. but this does it

EDIT: of course this should go in some kind of myRound() function

I read about the problem with your 1 needing to round up to 1000.
this behaviour is controverse compared to the rest - so you will have to add something like:

```
if(number < 1000)
{  number = 1000; return number; }
```

ontop of your function;

Comment: Yeah just wanted to see if maybe there was a solution within the .round, thank you either way :D

Comment: yeah, reusing that function makes sence :) but sometimes it saves time just typing it down - especially with this specialcase behaviour .. hoped it helped you anyway

Answer (score 2):

***Not*** the exactly point, but to round a number like 1250 to 1.2k or 55730 to 55,7m you might use something like:

```
let value = 90731+'';
let len = value.length;
let sym = len>6?'m':'k';
let hundred = (len==9||len==6);
if(len>3){
  value = value.slice(0,-3)+(hundred?'':'.'+value.charAt(1))+sym;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

So this function below allow you to roundUp a number to the nearest *near*, basically you can roundUp a number to the nearest 10, or 1000 by just passing near 10,1000. That is all.

For instance, if i want to roundUp 10 to nearest 10, it should not return 20 as in the accepted answer, it should return 10.

```
function roundUp(number,near){
  if(number%near===0) return number;
    return  parseInt(number / near) * near+near;
  
}

console.log(roundUp(110,10)) // 110
console.log(roundUp(115,10)) // 120
console.log(roundUp(115,100)) // 200
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. It will help other users to understand your approach easily.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is especially important when answering old questions (this one is 6.5 years old) with existing answers. How does this answer improve upon what's already here?